# Plotting a graph using a function applied to elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, montecarlo

I'm trying to plot a graph where the x-values are denoted by the array below:

```
player_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

And the y values correspond to the value of the function below, when each of the elements in player_number is passed through it.

```
def success_rate(player_number):
```

which returns a single value
My issue is that I am unable to to plot the graph in the following way:

```
plt.scatter(player_number, success_rate(player_number))
```

I receive the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

I'm trying to get each of the values in player_number to produce a

The full details of my code can be seen below, I'm coding a Squid Game bridge Simullation.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#tiles indexed 1-19, with an index of 0 meaning the player was unlucky enough to make it on to 0 tiles
#function to output the furthest tile safely reached
def furthest_safe_tile(total_tiles):
    if total_tiles == 0:
        return total_tiles
    for k in range(1, (total_tiles + 1)):
        current_probability = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if k == total_tiles:
            return k
            break
        elif current_probability < 0.5:
            return k
            break


success_or_failure = []
number_contestants = 16


def tiles():
    number_eliminated_tiles = 0
    for i in range(number_contestants):
        tile_advance = furthest_safe_tile(19 - number_eliminated_tiles)
        number_eliminated_tiles = tile_advance + number_eliminated_tiles
        if number_eliminated_tiles == 19:
            success_or_failure.append(0) #0 meaning success
        else:
            success_or_failure.append(1)
    return success_or_failure


giant_list = []
for y in range(1000):
    giant_list = giant_list + tiles()


def success_rate(player_number):
    running_total = 0
    number_of_values_for_each_player_number = len(giant_list) // 16
    for p in range(0, number_of_values_for_each_player_number):
        running_total = running_total + giant_list[(player_number-1) + (16 * p)]
    success_value = (number_of_values_for_each_player_number - running_total) / number_of_values_for_each_player_number
    return success_value


player_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]



plt.style.use('grayscale')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.scatter(player_number, success_rate(player_number), alpha = 0.4, c = 'black', s = 50, marker = '.')
plt.xlim(1, 16)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.title("A graph Showing the Probability of Each contestant not Dying (Monte Carlo Method)")
plt.ylabel("Probability of Life")
plt.xlabel("Contestant Number")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your `success_rate` method doesn't look to be vectorized?  Instead of `success_rate[player_number]`, try `[success_rate(p) for p in player_number]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepare data correctly to use with `.scatter()` function.

Here is the modified code and the output plot:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#tiles indexed 1-19, with an index of 0 meaning the player was unlucky enough to make it on to 0 tiles
#function to output the furthest tile safely reached
def furthest_safe_tile(total_tiles):
    if total_tiles == 0:
        return total_tiles
    for k in range(1, (total_tiles + 1)):
        current_probability = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if k == total_tiles:
            return k
            break
        elif current_probability < 0.5:
            return k
            break


success_or_failure = []
number_contestants = 16


def tiles():
    number_eliminated_tiles = 0
    for i in range(number_contestants):
        tile_advance = furthest_safe_tile(19 - number_eliminated_tiles)
        number_eliminated_tiles = tile_advance + number_eliminated_tiles
        if number_eliminated_tiles == 19:
            success_or_failure.append(0) #0 meaning success
        else:
            success_or_failure.append(1)
    return success_or_failure


giant_list = []
for y in range(1000):
    giant_list = giant_list + tiles()


def success_rate(player_number):
    running_total = 0
    number_of_values_for_each_player_number = len(giant_list) // 16
    for p in range(0, number_of_values_for_each_player_number):
        running_total = running_total + giant_list[(player_number-1) + (16 * p)]
    success_value = (number_of_values_for_each_player_number - running_total) / number_of_values_for_each_player_number
    return success_value

player_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

plt.style.use('grayscale')
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))

# Fails here
#plt.scatter(player_number, success_rate(player_number), alpha = 0.4, c = 'black', s = 50, marker = '.')

# Begin my code
rates = []
for ea in player_number:
    rates.append(success_rate(ea))
plt.scatter(player_number, rates, alpha = 0.4, c = 'black', s = 50, marker = '.')
# End mycode

plt.xlim(1, 16)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.title("A graph Showing the Probability of Each contestant not Dying (Monte Carlo Method)")
plt.ylabel("Probability of Life")
plt.xlabel("Contestant Number")
plt.show()
```

[image: outputplot]

Alternately, you can change the line of errorneous code

```
plt.scatter(player_number, success_rate(player_number), ...
```

to

```
plt.scatter(player_number, [success_rate(x) for x in player_number], alpha=0.4, c='black', s=50, marker='.')
```

and get the same result.